# How to configure environment variables in Ubuntu?

Tags: java, environment-variables, maven-3

My environment variables are correct? What is the correct way to use them in Ubuntu? I put them at the end of .bashrc file or edit the end of `/etc/environment` to able to use the `$JAVA_HOME` and `$M2_HOME` configuration and on my user?

#### $JAVA_HOME

JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/​" 
CLASSPATH="JAVA_HOME/lib/:$CLASSPATH" 
PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin/:$PATH"

#### $M2_HOME

M2_HOME="/usr/share/maven/" 
M2="$M2_HOME/bin" 
PATH="$M2:$PATH"
    PATH=$M2:$PATH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In bash you can set variables like this:

`export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/​`

```
export CLASSPATH=JAVA_HOME/lib/:$CLASSPATH
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin/:$PATH
export M2_HOME=/usr/share/maven/
export M2=$M2_HOME/bin
export PATH=$M2:$PATH
```

for more info on environment variables you can read https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables

Comment: the export when I restart the computer lose the settings

Comment: refer the link in answer and read the point Persistent environment variables

Comment: From what I understand Variable expansion is a form of Persistent environment variables, but does not work in /etc/environment.

Comment: I think that the way will be putting them at the end of .bashrc file

Comment: You can add it to the file .profile or .bashrc or your current shell profile file (located in your home directory). Then, each time you open your shell it will be loaded. This will help you http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117467/how-to-permanently-set-environmental-variables

Comment: I do not remember what was the command to load the current settings without restarting the computer, Prashant Chikhalkar you let me know?

Comment: load current settings? I'm not getting you .. Are you able to set env var succesfully?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26673/discussion-between-prashant-chikhalkar-and-ricardoramos).

Comment: Hello Prashant Chikhalkar, insert the environment variables at the end of .bashrc file as your suggestion and did the tutorial: http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2012/08/how-to-get-environment-variables-in.html,   but only shows the PATH variable and does not show the Java home. `PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"`

Comment: It seems that everything is working because when I type in the terminal the command: `$ echo $JAVA_HOME`  show `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/​` and `$ echo $M2_HOME` show `/usr/share/maven/`. Because my Java code does not display the environment variables $ JAVA_HOME and $ M2_HOME? Java Code: http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2012/08/how-to-get-environment-variables-in.html